# Tabulator data tree: Set row padding for only one level

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using the Tabulator data tree. I would like to change the row padding only for level 0. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly, I havent tested this but if you use a [rowFormatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/print#formatters) and use getElement() on it, you might be able to change the padding that survives anything Tabulator does behind the scenes. When I do an inspect of one of my rows, I see it sets padding-left:0px , so at least you know that Tabulator uses that, and if you change it, it might get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

rowFormatter was the key. Thank you!

```
rowFormatter:function(row){
    if(row._row.modules.dataTree.index == 0){ //level 0
        var cells = row.getCells();
        cells.forEach((cell) => {
            cell.getElement().style.paddingTop = "24px";
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: very dangerous to use internal data structures from Tabulator like that. If he makes a change, your code will break. Try row.getTreeParent() instead. getTreeParent() returns false if it has no parent .ie level=0